# Pasar fecha GTM 0 a local

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Quiero pasar una fecha que esta en GTM0 a mi hora local, según *momentjs* es de [**esta manera**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/), pero no logro convertir la fecha a mi hora local.

```js
moment.locale('es');

let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48';

let fecha_origin = moment(fecha).format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Fecha original: ', fecha_origin);

let fecha_local = moment(fecha).utc().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Conversión: ', fecha_local);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

**Actualización 1:**

Se supone que mi hora local es -5, en cambio hace un +5 cuando hago la conversión.

[image: resultado]

Comment: Yo lo pruebo y me funciona correctamente. Me muestra la fecha -3 (bs as / argentina). El problema no está en tu código sino mas bien en tu configuración regional.

Comment: @FranIslas cambie la configuración regional, reinicie y no se soluciona.

Comment: ejecutando la demo que dejaste, tampoco te funciona? Digo para descartar la configuración de tu aplicación web.

Comment: @FranIslas es capture que coloque en la actualización es de la demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos primero a entender cómo funcionan las fechas con moment.js, analizando ejemplos, pero primero:

```
moment.locale('es');
```

Esto sólo afecta al idioma, es decir, si se va a escribir Dec(ember) o dic(iembre), no a la hora. Por tanto podemos descartarlo como causa de problemas

```
let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48';
```

Defines un momento en un formato *estándar*. ¿Pero, qué momento es? Hagamos unas pruebas para comprobarlo. Yo estoy en GMT+1 (España):

```
let momento = moment();

console.log('sin formato', momento);
//sin formato "2018-12-14T16:49:56.834Z"

console.log('con formato', momento.format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A'));
//con formato 14 de Dec del 2018 a las 05:49:56 PM
```

Ya vemos una diferencia: sin formato se usa la hora *Zulú* (por eso la Z final), mientras que cuando se usa formato, se usa la Zona Local del sistema operativo de mi máquina.

La hora Zulú es la hora [UTC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado), que coincide con GMT+0

Ahora probemos a *parsear* una fecha:

```js
let fecha  = '2018-12-07 22:56:48'; //sin zona definida
let fecha2 = '2018-12-07 22:56:48+01:00'; //con mi zona
let fecha3 = '2018-12-07 22:56:48Z'; //con zona 00
let momento = moment(fecha);
let momento2 = moment(fecha2);
let momento3 = moment(fecha3);

//al no definir la zona se muestra siempre hora Zulu:

 
//asume mi zona del SO, le resta 1 hora
//En tu caso esta ejecución debería sumar 5 horas
console.log('sin formato', momento);

//especificamos que la zona es +1, le resta 1 hora para mostar la hora Zulú
console.log('sin formato', momento2);

//Explícitamente es Zulú, no tiene que sumar o restar
console.log('sin formato', momento3);

const formato='DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A';

//Al usar un formato, se usa la hora local
console.log('con formato', momento.format(formato));
console.log('con formato', momento2.format(formato));
console.log('con formato', momento3.format(formato)); //Se le suma una hora a la Zulu

//formato, pero pidiendo utc:
console.log('con formato en UTC (+00)', momento.utc().format(formato));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Por tanto vemos que el problema es que cuando escribes:

```
let fecha_local = moment(fecha).utc().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Conversión: ', fecha_local);
```

Estás cometiendo un error de concepto:

```
 moment(fecha) //parseas una hora local (-5)
  .utc() //pides que te la traslade a UTC (le suma 5 horas)
  .format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A'); // y la muestras
```

Answer (score 7):

El problema es que estás intentando **parsear** una fecha que no tiene información de UTC en ningún lugar. Eso se puede saber inmediatamente si descomponemos la fecha que usas como input

```
let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48'
```

La fecha sería `2018-12-07` y la hora `22:56:48` separados por espacio

La información del UTC debe ir al final como `+hh:mm` o `-hh:mm`, si está en UTC debería ser `+00:00`

> Si el fragmento del tiempo es incluido, un offset de UTC puede ser incluido también como +-HH:mm, +-HHmm, +-HH o Z

Cambiando la fecha input funciona perfectamente. Yo usé `T` como separador.

```js
moment.locale('es');

let fecha = '2018-12-07T22:56:48+00:00';

let fecha_origin = moment(fecha).local().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Fecha en local: ', fecha_origin);

let fecha_local = moment(fecha).utc().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('En utc: ', fecha_local);
console.log('Offset', moment().utcOffset() / 60);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

La otra forma es que en lugar de `moment(fecha).utc()` uses `moment.utc(fecha)` directamente ya que segun dices viene en utc del server.

```js
moment.locale('es');

let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48';

let fecha_origin = moment.utc(fecha).local().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Fecha en local: ', fecha_origin);

let fecha_local = moment.utc(fecha).format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('En utc: ', fecha_local);
console.log('Offset', moment().utcOffset() / 60);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

La diferencia está en **como se procesa**. Recuerda que tu fecha inicial no tiene información del offset asi que si usas `moment(fecha).utc()` lo que hará es *interpretarlo* como hora local y luego *convertirlo* a utc sumando o restando horas (de ahí tu problema). Si lo especificas `moment.utc(fecha)` entonces lo *interpretará* como utc directamente, o sea `+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

utc() debería ir en la fecha original y en la fecha local aplicar local().Con el siguiente ejemplo ami me funciona perfectamente. Debería quedar así el código:

```js
moment.locale('es');

let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48';

let fecha_origin = moment(fecha).utc().format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Fecha original: ', fecha_origin);

let fecha_local = moment(fecha).format('DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A');
console.log('Conversión: ', fecha_local);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera obtengo la fecha con la zona horaria que necesitas: La imagen muestra la captura en la consola. *(Haz la prueba en local)*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<script>
 moment.locale('es');

 let fecha = '2018-12-07 22:56:48';

 let fecha_local = moment.utc(fecha).toDate();
 console.log('Conversión: ', fecha_local);
</script>
```