# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha correcta?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy usando **moment.js**. Tengo un problema puesto que escribo en un fichero JSON cierta información, y con esta, van algunos valores los cuales son fechas. Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema viene cuando yo obtengo la fecha.

Uso:

`let dateToday = moment().parseZone();`

Lo cual me devuelve la fecha:

```
moment("22-07-2019T10:11:00.123")
```

Y esta fecha es correcta, pero cuando yo escribo en el fichero ese valor lo que me escribe es siempre dos horas menos: `22-07-2019T08:11:00.123` ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? No entiendo la razón por la cual si el valor de la fecha es x porqué al escribir las horas son x-2.

Comment: ¿Como escribes en el "fichero" la fecha? Es posible que al escribirla se parsee el formato de UTC a GMT o al revés.

Comment: Hola x3k_js, gracias por responder. El caso es que es un fichero JSON, el cual leo y meto esta información en un objeto JSON. Una vez obtengo el objeto JSON le cambio una propiedad la cual es una fecha, y una vez cambiadas todas las partes que necesito, vuelvo a escribir ese JSON en el fichero, con lo cual todo se actualiza, pero la fecha lo hace de esa forma.

Comment: Si tu fecha ya está en UTC, tendrás que definirlo: `let dateToday = moment().utc().parseZone();` de lo contrario si no esta en UTC tendras que formatearla: `let dateToday = moment().parseZone().format();`

Comment: No controlo muy bien esta librería, pero acabo de probar un poco en jsfiddle, al final te crea un objeto, como lo tratas a la hora de "imprimirlo" o guardarlo en el json.

Comment: Para escribir en el fichero lo que utilizo Fyle System de node.js. Utilizo readFile() para leer y writeFile para escribir. Lo que hago es "promisificar" estos métodos con el util de node.js. En el momento en el que voy a escribir paso como datos el objeto JSON a string, y lo paso como parámetro en el método de escritura después después de la ruta: `await writeFileP(__dirname + '../../../config/shops.json', JSON.stringify(shopsConfigFile));`

Comment: El formato de fecha sale bien, al sacarlo en consola las horas son correctas. Cambia cuando es escrito o al asignarlo a la propiedad del objeto.

Comment: @H.Díaz He escrito una respueta donde se puede ver los snippets y su funcionamiento. Prueba eso, si no te sirve en tu caso, tendras que realizar un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Relacionado: [Pasar fecha GMT a local](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220571/pasar-fecha-gtm-0-a-local)

Answer (score 3):

Como te he puesto en el comentario, tu tienes esto:

```
let dateToday = moment().parseZone();
```

A lo que yo te aconsejo que definas siempre el formato de UTC.

**Si tu fecha ya esta en UTC:**

```
let dateTodayUtc = moment().utc().parseZone();
```

Snippet:

```js
let dateTodayUtc = moment().utc().parseZone(); // Si tu fecha ya esta en UTC deberias definirlo. 
console.log("Fecha antes: "+dateTodayUtc.toString());

let json = {
  "id" : 1,
  "fecha": dateTodayUtc
}

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/es.js" integrity="sha256-bETP3ndSBCorObibq37vsT+l/vwScuAc9LRJIQyb068=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Si tu fecha no está en UTC la formateas:**

```
let dateTodayFormatToUtc = moment().parseZone().format();
```

Snippet:

```js
let dateTodayFormatToUtc = moment().parseZone().format(); // Si tu fecha no esta en UTC la formateas.
console.log("Fecha antes: "+dateTodayFormatToUtc.toString());

let json = {
  "id" : 1,
  "fecha": dateTodayFormatToUtc
}

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/es.js" integrity="sha256-bETP3ndSBCorObibq37vsT+l/vwScuAc9LRJIQyb068=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad es que ya había llegado a sacar esos valores, pero tengo la duda de que si este formato: `2019-07-22T11:41:27+02:00` será completamente válido y podré realizar comparaciones con otras fechas normalmente.

Comment: @H.Díaz El formato se lo puedes dar tu como quieras, en este caso esta el "default", pero tu puedes hacer: `.format("DD [de] MMM [del] YYYY [a las] hh:mm:ss A");` como se puede ver en la respuesta de Pablo Lozano [Pasar fecha GMT a local](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220571/pasar-fecha-gtm-0-a-local)

Comment: Al utilizar el método toString() se me genera un String como este: `Mon Jul 22 2019 13:04:04 GMT+0200`. No es como en tu caso en el cual la propiedad adquiere el valor de la fecha. Además el valor obtenido por la propiedad fecha es literalemente: `moment("Mon Jul 22 2019 13:04:04 GMT+0200")` Una vez lo escribo en el fichero coge la fecha, y la escribe con dos horas menos haga lo que haga, incluso si yo escribo una nuevo fecha `new Date(2019,07,22,9,0,0)` y me pone "2019/06/22T07:00:00" aquí quita dos horas, aunque yo haya puesto 9 como hora.

Comment: @H.Díaz Entonces deberás crear un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para ver donde puede estar el problema, Intenta crear un snippet donde ocurra lo mismo que te ocurre a ti.